# c++ why returning pointer works, but returning address not?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following code where I first define struct ListNode to represent an integer, then a function receiving two integers as ListNodes and returning their sum:

```
struct ListNode {
 int val;
 ListNode *next;
 ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 };
 ListNode* addTwoNumbers( ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2 ) {
    ListNode head; 
    ListNode* dummy = &head;
    ListNode* pNode1 = l1;
    ListNode* pNode2 = l2;
    int i1, i2, value;
    int takeover = 0;
    while( pNode1 != nullptr || pNode2 != nullptr )
    {
        i1 = ( pNode1 != nullptr )? pNode1 -> val : 0;
        i2 = ( pNode2 != nullptr )? pNode2 -> val : 0;
        value = i1 + i2 + takeover;
        takeover = value / 10;
        (dummy -> val) = value % 10;
        dummy -> next = new ListNode(); 
        dummy = dummy -> next;
        if ( pNode1 != nullptr)
            pNode1 = pNode1 -> next;
        if ( pNode2 != nullptr )
            pNode2 = pNode2 -> next;
    }
  if ( takeover > 0 )
    dummy -> val =  takeover;
  return &head;
}
....
ListNode* l1=..., l2 = ...;
ListNode* pN = new ListNode;
pN = addTowNumbers(l1, l2);
```

but now pN is equal nullptr;
but if in the function definition of addTwoNumbers, we use
ListNode* head;

```
ListNode* head;
ListNode* dummy = head;
....
return head;
```

it would work; why?

Comment: `return &head;` return address of local variable, so dangling pointer. Your compiler might warn you with appropriate flag/warning level.

Comment: `ListNode* head; ListNode* dummy = head;` is UB, as `head` is not initialized... Did you mean `ListNode* head = new ListNode; ListNode* dummy = head;`?

Comment: `ListNode* pN = new ListNode; pN = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);`: You leak memory, it should simply be `ListNode* pN = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);`.

Comment: In case you don't know what a dangling pointer is, here is a [link to the corresponding Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: yes, acctually it is ListNode* head = new ListNode; ListNode* dummy = head; thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is here.

```cpp
    ListNode head; 
    ListNode* dummy = &head;
```

`head` is initialized locally, that means after function call, it is expired. Create dummy node like below.

```cpp
ListNode *dummy = new ListNode(0);
```

Another mistake. You don't need to initialize `pN` variable. You can directly assign the result of the function.

```cpp
ListNode* pN = addTowNumbers(l1, l2);
```

Comment: but if  I use ListNode* head = new ListNode; ListNode* dummy = head;...return head;head is as well initialized locally, right? but then calling ListNode* pN = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2) would work. why?

Comment: `new` allocates the memory dynamically. And that memory is not destroyed even after the function call ends. But local variables are stored in stack, which are destroyed after the function call. Also, It's your responsibility to "free" or "delete" your memory which was allocated by `new`.